# Tomcat-7 Error while starting in eclipse Luna, Error starting static Resources

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have created Spring MVC application and I am using Tomcat-7, Maven and eclipse luna. I am starting server from eclipse, but its giving me below error :

```
 SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base E:\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\Spring3HibernateIntegration does not exist or is not a readable directory
at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4906)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5086)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

 Jan 03, 2015 10:19:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
 SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
```

Could somebody please help me.

Comment: Refresh your project, clean it, rebuild and publish.

Comment: @Pavel : I did that already, but didn't help. And one more thing this issue occurs sometimes not always when I start my Tomcat server.

Comment: Clean your tomcat work directory